# Change grid-template-columns on button click

Tags: jquery, css, css-grid

I am trying to change `grid-template-columns` using jQuery, but I cannot get it to work. Here is my code:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.grid').css('grid-template-columns', 'repeat(2, 1fr)');
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <button>Expand</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Expand</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Expand</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Expand</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

After the button is clicked every grid item is displayed as `1fr`. How can I get this working?

Comment: Well, what are you trying to achieve? The code is doing exactly what you've set it to do.

Comment: @Michael_B it displays as `"column"` not `"column column"`  after the button is clicked. `repeat(2,1fr)` should create two equally sized columns.

Comment: I'm not seeing that problem at all. I'm seeing two columns. https://jsfiddle.net/hdygvzjf/

Comment: Can you please be more specific ? Maybe are you trying to expand only one cell?